# Considerations when turning on RouteExistingFiles

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am looking to generate *some* CSS files dynamically in my Content folder.

At the moment, this folder has an ignore route (`routes.IgnoreRoute("Content/{*wildcard}");`) and, I'd like that to remain, as I don't need/want most of my content folders to go into the MVC request lifecycle.

**Example:**

```
 routes.MapRoute(
  "DynamicCSS",
  "Content/Css/Dynamic/{guid}.css",
  new { controller = "Site", action = "GenerateCSS" },
  new { guid = @"^([0-9a-fA-F]){8}([0-9a-fA-F]){4}([0-9a-fA-F]){4}([0-9a-fA-F]){4}([0-9a-fA-F]){12}$" }
);

//If the file has already been generated, IIS should just return the file, saving a request in MVC.
routes.RouteExistingFiles = true; //was formerly false

//Ignore routes
routes.IgnoreRoute("Content/{*wildcard}");
```

I have a couple questions/concerns about this setup:

- Will this work? Routes in ASP.NET MVC are lazy, but I don't know if the ignore routes are checked first. There's no documentation (I've Googled!) on this form of usage.
- Are there any security implications to consider when switching on `RouteExistingFiles`? I don't want IIS to pick up any of my Model/Views folders by directly referencing them.

Many thanks for any suggestions.

**Edit:**

After further research, I have found an [article](http://stevesmithblog.com/blog/ignoreroute-in-asp-net-routing-is-order-dependent/) on my first issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scott Hanselman got a blog post "Plug-In Hybrids: ASP.NET WebForms and ASP.MVC and ASP.NET Dynamic Data Side By Side" in which he talked about his too. http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PlugInHybridsASPNETWebFormsAndASPMVCAndASPNETDynamicDataSideBySide.aspx

Hope this helps,

Ray.