# routing problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have an actual folder with the same name as a controller. So the resulting link from this:

```
<li><%= Html.ActionLinkForAreas<BlaController>(c => c.Index(1), "BlaDiBla")%></li>
```

e.g.

> > www.bla.com/foldername  (where foldername = controller name)

Stopped working.

I am wondering how I can avoid this behaviour as easy as possible (I need the folder with the same name though).

Thanks.

Best wishes,

Christian

Comment: Best solution I've found so far is: routes.RouteExistingFiles = true; which might be too coarse grained. what do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIS does *not* get priority, but the ASP.net routing engine in System.Web.Routing looks for physical files (or directories) before looking at the Routes you have defined.

You can switch this at a global level with the [`RouteCollection.RouteExistingFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc680036.aspx) property, which will then give your route definitions priority over the file system.  Make sure you test all your routes when you change this!

See also this question [Considerations when turning on RouteExistingFiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402264/considerations-when-turning-on-routeexistingfiles).

Comment: Thanks. This seems to work: routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;
            routes.IgnoreRoute("Content/{*wildcard}");

Comment: Don't forget routes.IgnoreRoute("Scripts/{*wildcard}"); as well otherwise JS won't work!