# ASP.NET Routes Handler Won't Trigger for ASPX file

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, asp.net-mvc-routing

Lets say I have a route defined like so:

```
routes.MapPageRoute(""
                    , "{language}/customerservice.aspx"
                    , "~/customerservice.aspx"
                    , false
                    , new RouteValueDictionary { {"language", "en"} });
```

And in /customerservice.aspx I populate a literal like so:

```
lit_test.Text = RouteData.Values["language"].ToString();
```

I would expect the literal text to be "en" when I navigate to /customerservice.aspx, instead I get a null reference exception. At /en/customerservice.aspx it behaves as I would expect.

Is there a way to have routes run for aspx files that exist on disk?

Edit:

A route configured like so:

```
routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;

routes.MapPageRoute(""
                    , "customerservice.aspx"
                    , "~/customerservice.aspx"
                    , false
                    , new RouteValueDictionary { { "language", "en" } });
```

Will result in the literal being populated with "en", however the first scenario with the optional language parameter still fails with the RouteExistingFiles flag set to true.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use [RouteExistingFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routecollection.routeexistingfiles%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to force all requests (even for files that exist on disk) go through routing.

```
routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;
```

Search for the [RouteExistingFiles](http://www.bing.com/search?q=RouteExistingFiles) to find more info like [Considerations when turning on RouteExistingFiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402264/considerations-when-turning-on-routeexistingfiles).

Comment: That setting will make the route run for the aspx file when I don't include the optional {language} parameter in the route, but it will still exhibit the same behavior when I include the optional parameter.

Comment: @user1276017 - don't know. I'd add explicit route for "/customerservice.aspx" to see if it helps - at least it will clarify what part does not work.

Comment: I updated the question with more clarification regarding my first comment.